# How can i get response size of headers REST API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api

I know in headers we can get content length, which indeed gives Content body length But I need Response size of headers

For example:
API Response =

```
{
    "1": 1
}
```

If I print `console.log(res.getHeader('content-length'));` it gives 7 which is content length of body.
But I need response size of header which is 377Bytes(header + body) as shown in postman

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way to get the bytes of file is to download it , by using curl command in the following mannner:

> curl -so /dev http://www.yourip.org/http-your-file/ -w '%{size_download}'
>   where **-w/--write-out** 
>   defines what to display after a completed and successful operation

Comment: So for all APIs user hits do I need to download it every time? Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a NPM module to get object sizeof, you can install it with npm install object-sizeof

```
 var sizeof = require('object-sizeof');

 // 2B per character, 6 chars total => 12B
 console.log(sizeof({abc: 'def'}));

 // 8B for Number => 8B
 console.log(sizeof(12345));

 var param = { 
'a': 1, 
'b': 2, 
'c': {
  'd': 4
}
};
// 4 one two-bytes char strings and 3 eighth-bytes numbers => 32B
console.log(sizeof(param));
```

You can use it however you want in your code.
Example ::

```
console.log(sizeof(response.body));
```

Comment: because Postman calculates everything in the response even the headers and metadata sent along the response.
Try calculating the size of the entire response object and not only the body.
e.g sizeof(response)

Comment: For example size of above param is double as shown in response in postman